# DbContext SaveChange is not updating data in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Try to update the value of MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts using HTML Form. When I debug my code it shows b.MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts with updated value but nothing changes when SaveChanges() is executed

```
public ActionResult Submit(config asp) {
    using(var db=new DB()) {
        Operation op = new Operation();
        var result = op.Fetch();
        foreach (var b in result) {
            b.MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts = asp.MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts;
        }
        try {
            db.SaveChanges();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Content(e.Message);
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**Operation class**

```
public class Operation {
    public IEnumerable<config> Fetch() {
        using (var db = new DB()) {
            var query = from b in db.config
                        select b;
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is entity framework 5

Comment: what does fetch do?

Comment: What context are you using? Is it Entity Framework ? What I can see from the code is that an instance of `DbContext` is created, some data fetched, then copied with `.ToList()` and returned. Then some properties in this *disconnected* data are changed and then `.SaveChanges()` saves the same untouched context data because all changes were done to `List<aspnet_config>`. Try changing your `foreach` to iterate over `db.config` directly.

Comment: I retrieve data from database using LINQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.SaveChanges();` Is totally disconnected from `Fetch()`

I.e you need to save on the same context or *Attach* them to the context you are saving on

For instance

```
public IEnumerable<aspnet_config> Fetch(DB db)
{

    var query = from b in db.config
                select b;
    return query.ToList();    
}
```

**Update** comments from *Tetsuya Yamamoto*

> Return the `IQueryable` object from second context and use
>   `db.config.Attach(result`) method to attach it, then you can change
>   property value afterwards

**Update 2**

```
  foreach (var b in result) 
  {
     db.config.Attach(b);
```

Comment: how can I attach them to the same context

Comment: Return the `IQueryable` object from second context and use `db.config.Attach(result)` method to attach it, then you can change property value afterwards.

Comment: Not able to do so

Comment: @RahulKumarParihar what cant you do

Comment: As you said i made the return type IQuerable and db.config.Attach(result) but this line is giving error saying method has some invalid arguments

Comment: Method has some invalid arguements